# AR retrieving what information from XXXJSON page

Tags: android, json, url-design

I began to make an app similar to layar, I know it is quite tricky. But from the examples I get, all of the information is being retrieved from pages such as;

> [GeoNames](http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyWikipediaJSON)

OR

> [Twitter](http://search.twitter.com/search.json)

My question is what is contained  in those pages, I want to create my own page, to include the GEO locations I choose, can you give me a complete example of what to include in those .json files along with the structure of the url I should use to be able to make a call from an android app.

Thank you.

Comment: check APIs by Google request and esp. Response - Places, Maps. Eg.
https://developers.google.com/places/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete a.json file;

```
{
"status": "OK",
"num_results": 3,
"results": [
    {
        "id": "2827",
        "lat": "43.246061",
        "lng": "-79.807346",
        "elevation": "32.29999923706055",
        "title": "Penegal",
        "distance": "9.756",
        "has_detail_page": "1",
        "webpage": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buiud.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "2821",
        "lat": "43.546095",
        "lng": "-79.807346",
        "elevation": "0",
        "title": "Gantkofel",
        "distance": "9.771",
        "has_detail_page": "0",
        "webpage": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "2829",
        "lat": "43.446095",
        "lng": "-79.807346",
        "elevation": "21",
        "title": "Roen",
        "distance": "17.545",
        "has_detail_page": "1",
        "webpage": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suedtirolerland.it%2Fapi%2Fmap%2FgetMarkerTplM%2F%3Fmarker_id%3D2829%26project_id%3D15%26lang_id%3D9"
    }
]
}
```

Works like a charm!